# How can I count the rows in my custom OOP PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this simple custom `PDO` query that I've made as an object. How can I count the number of rows? I've surfed the internet for solutions, however nothing has worked.

Here's my PHP:

```
$days = DB::fetch("SELECT 'id' WHERE 'id' = 1;");
// Returns an error
$numrows = $days->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: `$days-fetchColumn()` is never going to work, that's not the way you access object properties.

Comment: You're missing a `>` right after `$days-`

Comment: I fixed the > and it still doesn't work

Comment: can you please respond, I've got to finish this job quickly

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 'id' = 1;

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the count in the query, I want to use PHP to count it

Comment: If you could count the no. of rows directly in query then why you want do do this using php.

Comment: Well to count using php just sotre result returned by query into a variable then use count function to get the no. of rows returned by that query .For ex: echo count($numrows);

Comment: I removed heaps of stuff from my query for demonstration purposes, so I actually do need to use PHP to do it. I've tried count($numrows) and that just returned 0

Comment: Dump your variable to check whether the query is returning some value.For ex: `var_dump($numrows);` .If is returns NULL then something is wrong with your query.

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM` part is missing in the `SQL`. The `SQL` should be as followed.

```
$days = DB::fetch("SELECT id FROM <table_name> WHERE id = 1;");
```